# Vertical file tab in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

By default all open files in your netbeans are displayed in a horizantal tab, just like a browser does.

I want my tabs to be listed vertically, is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the tabs representing opened files to be stacked in rows instead of laid out side-by-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the functionality you require was added to the NetBeans sources only a few weeks ago. You can view this changeset here: http://hg.netbeans.org/main/rev/e36924dd340d

So you should be able to set the tab positions in the `Options` if the version of the IDE you have was built after the change mentioned above (25 Jan 2012).

You can get the nightly builds [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/zip/).

Comment: Wow, great! I just filed this RFE: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209149

Comment: The [bug was fixed](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209149), but not ideally.

Answer (score 7):

Tools -> Options -> Appearance -> Tab placement